# sql count mismatch

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not able to understand the SQL query output :

```
SQL> select distinct(STATUS) from TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_CP_11035;

    InDelivery_SOMBe 
    In Delivery
    Complete
    Amended
    Cancelled
    Failed InComplete
 1   SQL> select count(*) from TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_CP_11035 where
    STATUS='Complete';
          1484
 2   SQL>  select count(*) from TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_CP_11035 where STATUS
    != 'Complete';
          3167
  3  SQL> select count(*) from TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_CP_11035;
          5091
```

The sum of count for the 1 and 2 queries should be same as the total count(3 query).Why is the sum differing from the whole count?
It seems like a dump question but i dont know why is this happening.
Please note that My question is not related to null check at all.It is the that 
sum(1+2)=3.1484+3167 !=5091.Why is the result different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is NULL values, which match none of your WHERE clauses, *including the last one*. Try

```
select count(*) from TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_CP_11035 where STATUS is null;
```

`where status = null` is never true, nor is `where null = null`. You have to use `is null`.

> The sum of count for the 1 and 2 queries should be same as the total count(3 query).Why is the sum differing from the whole count?

No, because the records with NULL are not matching query 1 or query 2, but they are counted in query 3.

1 + 2 + IS NULL should equal 3.

Answer (score 4):

`WHERE STATUS = NULL` won't work.  Nothing equals `NULL`.

Try `IS` instead of `=`...

```
select count(*) from TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_CP_11035 where STATUS IS null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Assuming p_key is a primary key for the table,

```
select count(p_key) from TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_CP_11035 where STATUS='Complete';
select count(p_key) from TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_CP_11035 where STATUS <> 'Complete';
select count(p_key) from TMP_ORDER_ACTION_PSTN_CP_11035 ;
```